# Running multiple Testcafé tests sequentially in Jenkins/Selenium Grid

Tags: jenkins, testing, automated-tests, selenium-grid, testcafe

Me and my colleagues developed some tests using Testcafé, with the goal in mind to have these tests be ran automatically on a daily basis using Jenkins and Selenium Grid, to give us insight in whether tests have ran succesfully (or not). All of the tests we developed work perfectly when ran from our local machines.

However, when we commit these tests to Jenkins, tests written in Testcafé using multiple tests inside one fixture fail. So to illustrate, a failing test is written as follows:

```
fixture('Smoketest').page(config.baseUrl);

test('Test 1', async (t) => {

//await loginHelper.login('system', 'user')
//more test code

});

test('Test 2', async (t) => {

//await loginHelper.login('system', 'user')
//more test code

});

test('Test 3', async (t) => {

//await loginHelper.login('system', 'user')
//more test code

});
```

Because of the website we run our tests on, the user can only be logged in once per session. So to illustrate, if the same user is logged in in one browser tab and logs in again in another browser tab, the user will be logged out of the other tab. When tests are run through Jenkins this is presumably where Selenium Grid comes in, since Selenium Grid tries to run tests in parallel with the same user in our case - which causes tests to fail since an user can only be logged in once.

So concluding, the ideal scenario would look like this: Fixtures should be allowed to run in parallel since they use different users, but tests INSIDE the fixtures should run sequential. What could be possible ways to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the described requirements (to authenticate a user only once), I can assume that you can use the [User Roles](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402845/guides/advanced-guides/authentication#user-roles) feature in your tests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Based on the documentation you provided, User Roles won't work because yes, the user is only authenticated once, however the tests will still run simultaneously in Jenkins, resulting in the user being logged out once multiple tests start running because only 1 session can be active per user.

Comment: I think an application should be tested in a way this application is designed to work. If it works only with one active user session, you should stick to this in your tests: either use different users or run these tests with completely disabled concurrency. I don't know details about how your pipeline with Selenium Grid is designed, but if you're using the [TestCafe Concurrency](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402830/guides/basic-guides/run-tests#run-tests-concurrently) mode, the only way I see is to put these tests in a different test suite and run TestCafe with disabled concurrency.